# Javascript variables of class type

Tags: javascript

I am seeing a piece of code . Its a .`js` file . I see that this file has the following kind of variable declared

```
var abc = {};
abc.Version="xxx";
abc.path="yyyy"
```

In other words the variable is used like a class . In saw the Javascript tutorials : [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_variables.htm)  & [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp) . But i see no mention of a class type variable .

What is it ? Wondering why isnt it mentioned in these websites .

Comment: The variable `abc` is an object, but there are no classes in JS. JS uses prototypical objects, not classical objects like Java and C++, et al. With JS, you can declare an object like your first line of code above, and then dynamically declare properties of that object on the fly, as is the case in lines 2 and 3 of your code above.

Comment: @HartleySan yes I have been using Java and C++ far too long . I never knew we could declare an object on the fly in js . Quite interesting . Can you post this as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `abc` is an object, but there are no classes in JS. JS uses prototypical objects, not classical objects, which is what languages like Java and C++ do.

With JS, you can declare an object like your first line of code above, and then dynamically declare properties of that object on the fly, as is the case in lines 2 and 3 of your code above.

Answer (score 3):

It is an object literal. What you're seeing on lines #2/3 are properties and associated values being dynamically added to it.

Answer (score 0):

they are properties on your object